# Color de fondo en la primera columna de una tabla

Tags: html, angular

Tengo una tabla que se llena con la siguiente estructura de datos

```
this.data = [
   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
   ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
   ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
   ['M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O']
];
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es agregar un color de fondo en la primera columna

[image: table]

Usé `[class.my-class]="i==0"`dentro del `td` haciendo uso del índice, pero me pintaría solamente la primera fila

Demo [StackblitzTable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awvs2g)

.HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let i=index">
    <td *ngFor="let c of row" [class.my-class]="i==0">{{c}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

.TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
      ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
      ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
      ['M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O']
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu template quedaría así.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let c of row; let i = index" [class.my-class]="i==0">{{c}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que hice es considerar el indice pero del bucle anidado.

Comment: cierto ni cuenta me di xD